# Java concurrency - is monitor blocked?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Is there a way to tell from one thread (say the one which locks a monitor object) if another thread is **blocked** / **waiting** on same monitor?

Example scenario -

> a "collector" thread reads data from a shared object, while the
>   "updater" thread might be blocked and waiting for the collection to
>   end. I would like the collector to know that when he finishes
>   collecting, a possible data update is pending which yield the
>   collected data might already be invalid.

In my case collecting might be a time consuming operation, and also in the next stage the "collector" thread analyzes the data for some more time, which might be a redundant operation in many cases where the data is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell from one thread (say the one which locks a monitor object) if another thread is block/waiting on same monitor?

No, not from the object itself.  You can, as @Evgeniy mentioned, use other of the `java.util.concurrent.locks.*` classes which allow you to view the queued members, but not from a `synchronized (lock)` type of object monitor.

> I would like the collector to know that when he finishes collecting, a possible data update is pending which yield the collected data might already be invalid.

How about having a `BlockingQueue` of updates so the collector could check the queue and see if it is non-empty. The updater thread(s) would just be adding `Update` information to the `BlockingQueue` and the collector would dequeue the updates and make the adjustments.  It then could check the length of the queue and make a decision about whether or not it needed to move into analysis mode.

```
private BlockingQueue<Update> updateQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Update>();
...
// called by the updater thread(s)
public void updateData(Update update) {
    updateQueue.put(update);
}
// called by the collector
public void collect() {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        Update update = updateQueue.take();
        updateValues(update);
        if (updateQueue.isEmpty()) {
           analyzeData();
        }
    }
}
```

Regardless of how you do it, you are going to need to account for the new data update using some other mechanism as opposed to checking all threads' blocked state.

Comment: Truth is my mechnism indeed uses a `BlockingQueue`. Checking it's length is an interesting idea!

Comment: I would like to accept your answer for being more helpful and constructive, but I can't do it when it says there's no posible way to achieve the original goal while from @Evgenniy's answer it's pretty obvious that there is. Please edit your answer.

Comment: I've tweaked my answer @Elist.  I had considered mentioning the other `Lock` classes but I didn't want to confuse my answer.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can get this info if you use `java.util.concurrent.locks` framework, ReentrantLock class has methods for that:

`Collection<Thread> getQueuedThreads()` - returns a collection containing threads that may be waiting to acquire this lock

`Collection<Thread> getWaitingThreads(Condition condition)` - returns a collection containing those threads that may be waiting on the given condition associated with this lock.

Answer (score 0):

One basic solution:  Add a binary flag and another monitor object:

```
volatile boolean  haveUpdate = false;
final Object      updateMonitor = new Object();
```

Set `haveUpdate` to  *true* when the updater thread has a new update, before it synchs on the data monitor.  Set it back to *false* at any point in the data synch block (where it's the only thread that can access the data anyway).

The collecting threads can check the value periodically and break if it's *true*.  When the collecting threads break, they should call `updateMonitor.wait()`, then loop back to collect again.  When the updater thread leaves the data synch block, it should call `updateMonitor.notifyAll()`.

Now, when any collecting thread sees there's an update coming or in progress, it will stop, wait for it to finish, then start up again.